# ¿Me gustaría saber qué código usar para que no graben mi activity, alguien sabe?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, seguridad

Lo que sucede es que tengo quiero una app mediante la cual cual no se pueda capturar ni grabar el activity, uso android studio y me especifique en java o kotlin, si es algún otro lenguaje también tengo algo en c++ no soy muy experto pero me gustaría que me ayudaran

Comment: Bienvenido , recuerda agregar lo que has tratado o investigado, revisar [ask], saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La solución que he probado para mis proyecto es utilizando el flag `FLAG_SECURE` que proteje a la vista de capturas de pantalla y gravación:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Este flag debe de ir antes de `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` para que al mostrar la vista ya tenga el flag de seguridad.

Cuando investigue esta solución mencionaban que fallaba con algunas versiones antiguas de moviles samsung, en mi caso no encontre ese tipo de problemas.

[link de la documentación](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SECURE)